# Tramway from airport to Casablanca

Tags: public-transport, morocco, casablanca

The [Casablanca Tramway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_Tramway) appears to run an “R” line from the [Mohammed V International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammed_V_International_Airport) to the city center according to [this map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_Tramway#/media/File:Plan_des_Trains,_Trams_et_du_Metro_Casablanca,_horizon_2030.png).

[This 2015 news announcement](http://www.oncf.ma/Pages/Actualite/Aeroport_CasaPort2015.aspx) seems to say that there is indeed a line now running to Casa-Port from the airport. But neither my French nor Google Translate are very trustworthy. So, I'm not quite sure.

➠ Can one take a tramway from the airport to the city?

- If so, how?
- Where is the station relative to the airport?
- What is the cost?
- What methods of payment?
- How often does it run, and what hours?
- How easy is it to figure out? Is there only a single tramway line running, so no way to get on the wrong one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes and no**: The [tramway](http://www.casatramway.ma/) does not go to the airport, but the [Al Bidaoui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Bidaoui) regional rail does, connecting it to [Casa-Voyageurs station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casa-Voyageurs_railway_station):

> The train station is situated at level -1 in the arrivals area of
>   Terminal 1. Trains depart from the airport to Casablanca or viceversa
>   every hour between 03:00h to 22:00 approximately. Journey time is
>   about half an hour and the ticket costs 30 MAD (around 3 USD).

(courtesy [casablanca-airport.com](https://www.casablanca-airport.com/transportation.php); not the [official website](http://www.onda.ma/en/Our-Airports/Casablanca-Mohammed-V-Airport#accesAe-232), but more useful)

The map you linked to is a plan for 2030 showing current and future lines for both tram and train ("R").  [A map of actual extent of the current tram system](http://www.casatramway.ma/files/large/adeb1adc7422fbaed5687a20880d283d.jpg) is available on the [tram's official website](http://www.casatramway.ma/).

Answer (score 3):

There is no tram, but the train is easy to navigate for a foreigner. You can withdraw cash from your foreign credit card in the airport terminal and pay in cash.

With basic French, you can check the timetable at http://www.oncf.ma/Pages/Horaires.aspx - search for trains from AEROPORT Med V - CASA VOYAGEURS

Trains are (currently) hourly, and there’s only one line so you can’t go wrong.